# Enable MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

As per PHP documentation, mysql needs to be enabled with PHP.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php

PHP 5.0.x, 5.1.x, 5.2.x

MySQL is not enabled by default, nor is the MySQL library bundled with PHP. Read this FAQ for details on why. Use the `--with-mysql[=DIR]` configure option to include MySQL support. You can download headers and libraries from » MySQL.

I am using PHP version 5.1.6
How do I enable the MySQL extension to be used with PHP?

Comment: What operating system and OS version?

Comment: Which OS are you using? Most Linux distributions provide a separate package, such as `php5-mysql` which will automatically enable MySQL when installed.

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yum install php-mysql

This will pull in all dependencies.

EDIT: see also https://serverfault.com/